# Check if Gift Vouchers Code is used in an Oder in Open Cart

Tags: php, opencart

Is there any way that we can check if the Customer has used the Gift Vouchers for the order ?

Actually what i want to do is , i have Created some Gift Vouchers code from the admin panel and sending them to user, Now i want some restrictions like User can use this Gift Vouchers code only once.

Just want to know if it is possible or not . And if it is possible then what will be the steps i will have to follow.

Comment: What is your Opencart version?

Comment: i am using Opencart Version 2.0.1.1

Comment: I am not too familiar with vouchers, but from looking at it I think this is how it works - a one time voucher. Have you tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gift vouchers (or Gift Certificates) are one time use only, if you attempt to use it again you will get a "Warning: Gift Voucher is either invalid or the balance has been used up!" message.

Gift vouchers can be created in the Admin or purchased by a customer through

index.php?route=account/voucher

You are probably confusing terms "Gift voucher" and "Coupon"

Comment: Correct !!! 
I found some usefull link for the same
http://docs.opencart.com/sale/gift-voucher/